# Omitting and including the definite and indefinite articles

Tags: articles

- Use A(AN) when you are talking about a thing in general, NOT a specific thing. When talking about a thing which is new, unknown, or introduced to a listener for the first time. Also use A(AN) when you are asking about the existence of something.
- Use THE when talking about something which is already known to the listener or which has been previously mentioned, introduced, or discussed.

I kind of understand the difference between the definite and indefinite articles. However, I don't quite understand when you should use the articles and when you should omit articles.

For example, when your classmate, John, asked you for ***photos*** of lecture notes and you send them via email. Do you write **please see attachments** because attachments is plural and he is seeing these attachments for the first time or **please see the attachments** because you're tell him to see these specific attachments and he knows what the attachments are(photos of lecture notes)?

Another example, you were driving, saw a abandoned car in the middle of the road, and sent a Snapchat of the abandoned car to your friends saying "someone left their car in the middle of **the road**!" Do you include the definite article because the road is introduced with the picture or if they know that road. Do you use the indefinite article **a road** if they don't know that road

Answer (score -1):

I would say

> Please see the attached photos.

And *the* is used because I assume the person I'm writing to can identity *which* attached photos I am talking about, and these are the ones attached to the email. This assumption on the part of the speaker that the hearer can identify the referent governs a great deal of definite article usage. But by no means does it cover all uses.

You could omit the definite article and write

> Please see attached photos.

or

> Please see attachments.

This usage is "truncated" and similar to headlinese, where nonvital words are omitted; it also sounds brusque and iis reminiscent or typical of old fashioned business language. But it's not wrong.

By the way, about 60% of the time we use *the* when mentioning something for the first time. (Read any article and you can confirm this.) Also, the indefinite article can refer to specific things, such as in *I married a woman from Minnesota*. The noun phrase refers to a specific woman. Furthermore, native speakers often employ *the* as way of signaling to the listener the introduction of a *new* topic. (*Have you heard about the new sandwich at Joe's restaurant?*) So, a lot of these rules you've listed are untrue, even if commonly found.

As for *someone left their car in the middle of the road!*, you can say *the* because (a) 'the road', like many many  other things, is idiomatic (another one is 'the night':  *someone hit my car in the middle of the night*). You can also think of it like this: (b) if the photo has a road in it, then we know which one you're talking about. This is true even if the person has never heard of or seen this road before.

Comment: Are there more of idiomatic nouns that require ***the***?

Comment: *Road* doesn't "require" *the*. It very often appears with *the* out of idiomatic usage. I think you should try to stop trying to learn rules about when to use articles and just expose yourself to more authentic English and casually observe how they are used.